# Mysql 8 (aurora) not using index

Tags: mysql, indexing, amazon-aurora

I have below table with a correct index I need for the query on 3 columns `(p_merchcreatecents_index)`.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `purchases` force index (p_merchcreatecents_index) 
WHERE `purchases`.`merchant_id` = 58729 
AND (
    created_at > '2023-04-14 08:25:42.879285' 
    and created_at <= '2023-05-14 08:25:42.879285' 
    and amount_cents > 0
    )
```

and this is the plan which is doing full table scan and not using the index

```
1 SIMPLE purchases  
ALL 
index_purchases_on_amount_cents,index_purchases_on_created_at,index_purchases_on_merchant_id_ip_agent,p_merchcreatecents_index  
1411820749  0.00    Using where; Using parallel query (3 columns, 4 filters, 0 exprs; 0 extra)
```

Can someone advise what is wrong ?

Thanks in advance !

```
CREATE TABLE `purchases` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `merchant_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_account_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `processor_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `sender_email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction_hash` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount_satoshis` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount_cents` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `receive_address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sender_address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `confirmations` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `before_swellrewards` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `paid_with` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fee_amount_cents` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `synced_to_analytics` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `gateway` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_repeat` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `applied_to_campaigns` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `is_refunded` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `referring_site` text,
  `referring_domain` text,
  `landing_site` text,
  `billing_country_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_address1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_address2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_zip` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_country_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_address1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_address2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shipping_zip` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_agent` text,
  `browser_country_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fraud_review` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `avs_postal_match` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `avs_street_match` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `avs_result_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `chargeback_protection` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `credit_card_bin` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cvv_result_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `credit_card_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `credit_card_company` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `has_swell_user` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `referral_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_agent_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `redemption_code_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `swell_discount_cost_cents` int DEFAULT '0',
  `referral_discount_code_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `affiliate_amount` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `eligible_for_vip_tiers` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `vip_tier_eligibility_job_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clerk_employee_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clerk_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_state` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `channel_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount_codes` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,
  `transactions` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_purchases_on_order_id_and_processor_id` (`order_id`,`processor_id`),
  KEY `index_purchases_on_amount_cents` (`amount_cents`),
  KEY `index_purchases_on_created_at` (`created_at`),
  KEY `index_purchases_on_customer_id` (`customer_id`),
  KEY `index_purchases_on_merchant_id_ip_agent` (`merchant_id`,`ip_address`,`user_agent_id`),
  KEY `index_purchases_on_order_id` (`order_id`),
  KEY `index_purchases_on_processor_id` (`processor_id`),
  KEY `index_purchases_on_referral_id` (`referral_id`),
  KEY `index_purchases_on_user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `p_merchcreatecents_index` (`merchant_id`,`created_at`,`amount_cents`),
  KEY `referral_discount_code_id` (`referral_discount_code_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `purchases_chk_1` CHECK (json_valid(`discount_codes`)),
  CONSTRAINT `purchases_chk_2` CHECK (json_valid(`transactions`))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2387558736 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 STATS_AUTO_RECALC=1;
```

When I use force index it does have a correct plan ..

```
explain SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `purchases` force index (p_merchcreatecents_index) WHERE `purchases`.`merchant_id` = 58729 AND (created_at > '2023-04-14 08:25:42.879285' and created_at <= '2023-05-14 08:25:42.879285' and amount_cents > 0)
```

This is the plan with force index:

```
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'purchases', NULL, 'range', 'p_merchcreatecents_index', 'p_merchcreatecents_index', '20', NULL, `1', '33.33', 'Using where; Using index'
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Aurora.  I don't think MySQL 8 would do anything other than use the "covering" index.